# Jetty Context Filter seems to work backward

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

So I've used the Jetty http web server as the core of a web server and have a process for specifying Filters and mapping them to incoming url requests to perform actions like authentication, logging and to restrict resource access to various folders.

The code that runs the HttpServer instance from the jetty API looks like this:

```
     org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHttpContext context = (ServletHttpContext)server.getContext(null,cono.getVirtualPath()); 

        // System.out.println(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "#####JETTY CONTEXT name: "  + context.getName() + " :cont path from getContext(): " + context.getContextPath() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

         String home = System.getProperty("server.home",cono.getHomePath());
         String subdirz = cono.getSubDir();
         String resourcepath = new File(home + File.separator + subdirz).getPath();
         System.out.println("Using Resource Path + subdir: " + resourcepath);
         boolean donote = false;
         if(Utilities.matchString(resourcepath,DPSConfig.getHttpServHome()) && cono.getId() > 0) {
           System.out.println(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "***Notice!*****************" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + " The resource path for this context is a subpath of the System Context Resource Path, some attributes may be overridden (as noted next to the affected item) as a result. " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "***Notice!*****************" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));  
           donote = true;
         }
         System.out.println("On Virtual context: " + cono.getVirtualPath());
         //make the resourcepath if it doesn't yet exist.
         Utilities.fileMakeDirs(resourcepath);
         //Set the resource base.
        context.setResourceBase(resourcepath);

           //Instantiate a new webapplicationhandler
         WebApplicationHandler whandler = new WebApplicationHandler();
```

The subsequent code loads the contexts with a handler and then starts the server. The problem arises when I am viewing resources mapped to one of the active contexts.

The resource file path is:

Z:\somefilecache

The virtual URL subdir is:

/goodies/

:Assuming hat somefilecache has a subdirectory called "images" I want to have the filter apply to all requests to that subdirectory to allow only authenticated requests. The WebContextFilter class does this by mapping a context subpath to the previous virtual url.

So the url:

http://www.myserver.com/goodies/images/deep/myfile.jpg

:should return "myfile.jpg" if the request is coming form an authenticated user and should return a 403 error if not.

For the context the configured subpath is "/images/*" which should trigger the WebContextFilter for any url's however what is happening is weird. The resources are NOT being blocked when the URL is:

http://www.myserver.com/goodies//////////images/deep/myfile.jpg

but ARE being blocked when the URL is:

http://www.myserver.com/goodies/images/deep/myfile.jpg

:this is obviously not what I want. The number of "/" shouldn't matter but does for some strange reason leaving open an easy way to get around the security of the context.

I've tried changing the context subdir to all kinds of variants: "//images/*" , "images/*" , "/*"

For all of them the WebContextFilter only gets invoked for the exact subdir string and not for the variants of "/" which then allow unauthorized file access!!

Is there a setting that allows me to cover all variants of the context subdir? Basically by inverting the WebContextFilter invocation.I did notice that the WebContextFilter "doFilter()" is NOT even called when the subpath in the requesting URL is not exactly correct...so the problem is happening before the WebContextFilter is even applied...the Server Context seems to be checking the URL for the subdir path string and if it is present then it invokes the WebContextFilter ...this is fine but I need to be able to tell it to pass all URL requests to the WebContextFilter.

I also tried to use regular expressions in the subdir thinking they were valid but the symbols are interpreted literally as part of the URL path string instead.

Any assistance that can be provided is greatly appreciated. I am using Jetty version 5.x.x

Comment: So it seems that the Filters are not being utilized at all IF a URL with extra forward slashes is added. This seems like a pretty nasty security bug. 

As mentioned above, if the url is:

http://www.myserver.com/goodies/images/deep/image.jpg

and the Filter is set to filter "/images/* " then the url above gets allowed when logged in but blocked when logged out as desired.

However,

If the url is:

http://www.myserver.com/goodies////images/deep/image.jpg

:then it get passed as valid no matter what the authentication state is since it never even enters the .doFilter() of the context Filter.

Comment: This is not what it should be doing!

Comment: All of the problems listed have been fixed with Jetty 7+, and further enhanced with Jetty 9 (to handle new security issues with Windows 8 and alternate streams)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt , I feared this was a deep bug...so are you saying I have to upgrade to 7? because my code would require a good number of changes it seems a lot of classes that were used in 5 have been deprecated...if i had access to the source for 5.x I'd fix the problem and rebuild my own distro. but I can't find the source (for anything before v. 7 ) online any more. I'll see if doing an upgrade to 9 doesn't force too many changes.